# How to print the non_Latin letters (Arabic alphabets) in right order in Python?

Tags: python, encoding, arabic

Arabic language is written in different way from Latin languages, it is written from right to left and the letters of one word are joined together.

My problem is that when i want to print Arabic word, it is printed from left to right and the letters are separated.
for example:

```
>>print("قطة")
ة ط ق
```

i use python 3.8.10.

Encoding of the file is UTF-8

Comment: The problem is the terminal design. Normal mode of terminal is just to print L to R. You should change terminal mode for R to L (but expect bugs on most of terminal). I just recommend you not to use the terminal but you own windows (also just with text), but with better font capabilities (liguatures, different width, etc.) very important to nice looking text in most scripts/languages

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called [arabic_reshaper](https://pypi.org/project/arabic-reshaper/) will solve this problem.